# ¿Por qué obtengo error leyendo un TXT y guardando en String[]?

Tags: java, array, string, txt

Estoy leyendo datos desde un txt y requiero guardar en un array.
Esto es lo que esta en el txt 8888 9999 9999 0000 7777 6666
Requiero meter estos datos en un Array.

```
try {
         
        //ruta de tu archivo
        String ruta = "Frutas.txt";
        BufferedReader br = getBuffered(ruta);
        //leemos la primera linea
        String line =  br.readLine();
        //creamos la matriz vacia
         while(line != null){
             String[] values = line.split(" ");
             String Frutilla=values[0];
            
          Fruta f = new Fruta(Fruta);//mando al metodo
```

CONSTRUCTOR

```
public class Fruta {
private String F;

    public Fruta(String F) {
         this.F= F;
    }

public void print(){
    System.out.println(F);


output es infinitamente
8888
8888
8888
8888
```

**Por que no me esta cargando los demas?**

Comment: Explícate un poco mejor porque no se entiende. ¿En el fichero tienes una sola línea con esos números, o cada número está en una línea? De todas formas, eso no puede compilar porque al constructor de `Fruta` le tienes que pasar un `String` y ahí le estás pasando algo que no es ni una variable, sino el nombre de la clase `Fruta`. Eso no puede compilar.

Comment: Fruta f = new Fruta(Frutilla); sería más correcto.

Comment: considera leer el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Te falta actualizar la variable line con la siguiente linea

Aquí estás pasandole la linea a la variable
String line =  br.readLine(); al llegar al while,en tu código,la variable linea tiene la primera linea y no se modifica en ningun momento. De ahí el bucle infinito.

Puedes dejar  `String line =  br.readLine();` si tienes una linea de encabezado-por el contrario cambiarlo a `String line = null;`

En resumen, lo unico que necisitarias cambiar el While para verificar que la nueva linea tiene contenido

```
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
```

Espero que te ayude.

Comment: Ambas respuestas me ayudaron. muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si dejas la lectura de la linea fuera del bucle evidentemente estas leyendo siempre la misma linea.

Deberías de meter dentro la lectura de la línea:

```
String line =  br.readLine();
   
while(line != null){
      String[] values = line.split(" ");
      line =  br.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Ambas respuestas me ayudaron. muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Se imprime de manera infinita porque el valor guardado en `line` no varía dentro del ciclo. Lo que se debe hacer es actualizar su valor dentro de la cadena. Quedaría así

```
try {
    String ruta = "Frutas.txt";
    BufferedReader br = getBuffered(ruta);
    String line =  br.readLine();
    String[] values;
    String Frutilla;
    Fruta f;
    while(line != null){
        values = line.split(" ");
        Frutilla = values[0];
        f = new Fruta(Fruta);
        line = br.readLine(); // Esta línea es la que falta
    }
//Continúa código aquí...
```

Por una cuestión de buenas prácticas y optimización, las variables `values`, `frutilla` y `f` (Fruta) deben declararse al inicio del método.